# Как изменить текст inline bytton aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, inline

Подскажите пожалуйста как отредактировать текст на инлайн кнопках
Вот код:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, types
from config import TOKEN


storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


async def on_startup(_):
    register_hendlers_admin()
    print('bot started')    # Преднастройки


class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    audio = State()


async def start_command(messege: types.Message):
    await messege.answer("Введите /upload или /up что бы загрузть трек")


async def process_upload_msic_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Загрузите аудио")
    await FSMAdmin.audio.set()


async def load_audio(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    audio_id = message.audio.file_id
    await message.answer("Принял.")

    INKB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)\
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="++", callback_data="thumbs_up"))\
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="+-", callback_data="OK_hand"))\
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="--", callback_data="thumbs_down"))

    await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio_id, performer="Performer", title="Title", reply_markup=INKB)
    await state.finish()


async def read_cleck_bytton(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    print(f"Нажата {call.data}")
    message_id = call.message.message_id
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    INKB_r = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3) \
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", callback_data="thumbs_up")) \
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="2", callback_data="OK_hand")) \
        .insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text="3", callback_data="thumbs_down"))
    await Bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id, reply_markup=INKB_r)


def register_hendlers_admin():
    dp.register_message_handler(start_command, commands=['start', 'help', 'h'])
    dp.register_message_handler(process_upload_msic_command, commands=['upload', 'up'])
    dp.register_message_handler(load_audio, content_types=['audio'], state=FSMAdmin.audio)
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(read_cleck_bytton)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Пытался это сделать через `bot.edit_message_reply_markup()` не получилось. Конкретно в этом примере вылазит ошибка что не передаётся параметр self. А в основном коде "Message identifier is not specified" Хотя я передаю ид чата и ид сообщения.

Comment: В общем с основным кодом я решил пробелему, всё чётко работает. А вот не помешало бы что бы кто то объяснил почему у меня в тестовом коде выдаёт ошибку параметра self

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
Bot.edit_message_reply_markup(...
```

Сделай

```
call.message.edit_message_reply_markup(reply_markup=...)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я только что с основным решил проблему. Просто переписал этот кусок кода и всё разаботало. А вот не понимаю почему ошибка параметра self в этом коде.

Comment: Ну потому что вы делаете через класс Bot, а не через экземпляр класса bot. Если у экземпляра класса есть свой Селф то у класса его нет и он требует явно показать какой именно бот использовать

Comment: @DeSkree если ответ вам подошёл примите ответ нажав на 'галочку' слева от ответа